# What is [[: not found error?

Tags: shell

I tried to execute a file containing a shell script.

I get an error called "[[: not found" error at the last line. How to resolve it?

Comment: You just hit the wonderful world of shell script portability issues. Likely you are the victim of a script writer who thinks that *All the world's a Bash* :-)

Comment: Probably the best solution is to change the first line to `#!/bin/bash`, assuming you don't mind having the script not be portable to systems that don't have `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 9):

`[[` is `bash`. `sh` wants the `[` variant.

Either change that to `/usr/bin/bash` (or wherever bash is located on your system), or adjust the expression accordingly:

```
if [ status_of_job -eq 0 ];
```

Comment: @user2391084: assuming the error is the one you posted as a comment to Marc, what is status_of_job exactly? (A separate program, right?)

Comment: The syntax error is because status_of_job is not an integer. :-) For a variable, that ought to be `$status_of_job` or `"$status_of_job"` .

Comment: `bash` is much more likely to be installed as `/bin/bash` than as `/usr/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 5):

`[` is actually an executable in linux. but `[[` is not.

Try

```
if [ status_of_job -eq 0 ]; then
```

(note the single `[]` set).

Comment: @user2391084: `status_of_job` is just a string. Do you mean `$status_of_job`? If so, you should also enclose it in double quotes: `if [[ "$status_of_job" -eq 0 ]]; then`

Comment: @MarcB `[` is an executable on Linux, but not all shells call it - it's often built in to the shell.

Answer (score 2):

This interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
```

Is either not `bash` or your file doesn't have the shebang in the right place.

`ls -l /usr/bin/sh` will tell you if it's a symlink to something other than bash.

If it is `bash`, then check that there's no leading characters before the `#!`.

Comment: Most Linux systems now use /bin/dash as their /bin/sh interpreter.  Don't modify the link and make bash the default, since this could massively impact system performance.  Dash is much more light weight and less memory intensive than its big brother.

Comment: I think "most" is a bit of a stretch. It's the default shell for Debian, but I'm not aware of any other distributions that have switched.

Answer (score 0):

You may find you stumble at other blocks later with POSIX shell related issues.  People don't really understand how much bash actually provides until it's taken away.  Take a look at this so you can hopefully avoid any other issues:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/shellix.html